# My HP printer is printing the print preview pages ONLY. I have print preview disabled. Printer worked fine when I put it to bed. Bad HPlip?

Tags: graphics, printing, hp

print preview is disabled
doesn't matter if * use office or Thunderbird to open the printer
I can not find anyplace that offers the option of printing the print preview
running Ubuntu 22.04.3
Ubuntu Pro is installed

Comment: I am considering the second idea for sure

Comment: More seriously, could you explain the problem more clearly? Maybe add some screenshots or pictures?